# x-www-form-urlencoded Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to connect to an API but it is using x-www-form-urlencoded ...and I am using this code. Please tell me the correct method.

```
AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeNone];
securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;


AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = nil;
manager.securityPolicy = securityPolicy;

[manager POST:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@"%@%@phone=%@&password=%@",BASE_URL,API_LOGIN,phone,password]
   parameters:nil
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          
          successBlock(responseObject);
          
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          
          NSLog(@"Server Error : %@", operation.responseString);
          errorBlock(error);
      }];

}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to set the http header for 'x-www-form-urlencoded' to communicate with your backend:

```
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

If this does not fix your errors, then try to validate your json object. 
You could also have a look to this question: [AFNetworking 3 x-www-form-urlencoded post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239506/afnetworking-3-x-www-form-urlencoded-post-data)